# how to sign the release xap file with my publisher ID

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, publisher

I have already use these Cordova Cli 5.0 to generate the xap file success
cordova build wp8 --debug => this will generate CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap file
cordova build wp8 --release => this will generate CordovaAppProj_Release_AnyCPU.xap file

I also have a "publisher ID" (xxxx-cccc-vvvv-bbbb)

so...
how to sign the release xap file with my publisher ID (because I want to publish to the winphone store)

PS
I have already a app in winphone store that made by PGB (build.phonegap.com)，and PGB will give a UI way to sign in the "publisher ID"
but now I am using Cordova Cli 5.0...so...